# Use animation in jekyll based Github pages

Tags: r, jekyll, knitr, github-pages

I have a little more complex question. I recently forked http://vis.supstat.com/ in order to set up a personal blog, which serves as a personal library with examples in R. In addition the blog is also a experiment to figure out the most efficient way to post from R mardown files locally created in RStudio to blog articles on a jekyll blog run on Github pages.

After I forked vistat on Github I changed the jekyll theme to hooligan (see https://github.com/dhulihan/hooligan) using

`rake theme:install git="https://github.com/dhulihan/hooligan.git"`,

which worked out well. After that I forked some articles from http://cpsievert.github.io/ who uses the same hooligan theme and a lot of animations in his articles like this one http://cpsievert.github.io/2013/05/yu-darvishs-deception-factor/. Unfortunately my forked article does not show this animations. It only shows a blank white square instead (see http://magnusmetz.github.io/2014/05/yu-darvishs-deception-factor/).

What is the reason for that? Would be great, if anybody could help me with that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Those animations are Adobe Flash animations, and are currently saved in the cpsievert repository. The correct link for the first animation is `http://cpsievert.github.io/figs/2013-05-15-yu-darvishs-deception-factor/ani.swf` while your site is pointing at `2014-05-15-yu-darvishs-deception-factor/ani.swf`

Unless you've download the ani.swf file in the `2014-05-15-yu-darvishs-deception-factor`folder, it won't show. On the other hand, just pull the content from the original source.

Hope I could help. Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Well if I compile my source files the generated figures are stored in the `figures/` folder. At the same page a few lines further you can see that the *.png is taken from the `figures/` folder. I can't explain why `figures/` is missing in 
`<div align="center">
 <embed width="504" height="504" name="plugin" src="2014-05-15-yu-darvishs-deception-factor/ani.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" /> 
</div>`
Of course I could adapt that in the HTML file, but I would prefer that the code is automatically generated correctly. Any hints, why is that?

Comment: Most probably your HTML file says otherwise :) Jekyll does not think things, it follows rules :)

Comment: I know that the necessary change is just within one line of code in one of all the files. But my problem is to identify the right file, which is responsible for the described issue. I know jekyll since one week. If you have any hints, where to start, let me know...